# i am getting fatal error random_bytes() in laravel 5

Tags: paypal, laravel-5

I am getting fatal error random_bytes() in laravel 5 after installing the 
"paypal/adaptivepayments-sdk-php":"v3.6.106" in composer.json

```
"require": {
        "laravel/framework": "5.0.*",
        "jacopo/laravel-authentication-acl": "1.3.*",
        "webpatser/laravel-countries": "dev-master",
        "yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle": "~5.0",
        "illuminate/html": "5.0.*@dev",
        "paypal/adaptivepayments-sdk-php":"v3.6.106"
    },
```

using composer. please share me any solution . i am stuck for last 3 hrs to solve this error.

i tried to comment the    nextBytes() in secureRandom.php file  but i think it is not a good idea.

Comment: Please post the exact error message you're seeing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`random_bytes` is a PHP function in PHP v7.0. You can install the missing package on PHP v5.x using composer.

Run `composer require paragonie/random_compat` and then try adding the affected library.

Source: https://github.com/paragonie/random_compat